# Como retomar as configurações padrões do editor do Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, resharper

Estava utilizando o ***ReSharper*** em período de avaliação e após o término do tempo de testes eu não quis adquirir e então desinstalei pelo **Painel de Controle** / **Programas e Recursos**, visto que não encontrei opção no ***Visual Studio*** para removê-lo.

Mas as configurações padrões do editor do ***Visual Studio*** não retornaram, como o verificador em tempo real de sintaxe.

Existe algo no ***Visual Studio*** que eu possa fazer para resolver isso?
Estou usando a versão **2013 Professional**.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

- No menu Tools, clique em "Import and Export Settings".
- Selecione "Reset all settings".
- Escolha se deseja fazer o backup da configuração atual.